# why is npm start is not starting the development server on my node project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, web-development-server, npm-start

I had to reset and download all my files again, including node.js. Now I am having problems starting my development server from my node.js project. Every time I try npm start the development server gets stuck[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKO6L.png). I have tried all of the trouble shooting that I know how to do. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?[the endpoint it is pointing to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8TLU.png)[here is the image of my scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c869c.png)

1. restarted modem
2. took down firewall
3. uninstalled node on my windows and redownloaded

Comment: What does your start.js script look like?

Comment: You should include the part of the code meant to start the server like `app.listen` in express; just seeing the command doesn't help us

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.